# Is there a way to put TODO marker in Confluence pages, then find all pages with this marker?

Tags: confluence

I'm looking for a way to put TODO markers on Confluence pages. SO I could then see TODO items in all documents. Just the way it's done in Visual Studio and other IDEs.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a page label for this, but it applies to the page as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

I have a user macro called **TODO** which I add to pages where I need to add/update content later.

It's simple to search for instances of this user macro on pages by searching for `macroName:todo` in Confluence search.

Here's the **TODO** user macro:

```
## Usage: {todo}
##
## Macro name: todo
## Macro title: TODO
## Macro has a body: N
## Body processing: No macro body
## Output: Selected output option
##
## Developed by: David Simpson <david@davidsimpson.me>
## Date created: 2011-sometime
## Installed by: David Simpson
## Icon URL: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/658119/web-shared-images/bomb.png
##
## @noparams
<span style="background:#900;color:#fff;border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px; padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;font-size:75%;">TODO</span>
```